# How to get the weeks number which are part of the month

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm creating 2d array for month days(to create Calendar Month view), and I need to calc the height of that array.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I have solved this in my way. I'm sharing the code with you:

```js
import moment from 'moment';

const height = calcMonthArrayHeight(moment());

function calcMonthArrayHeight(day) {
    const firstDay = day.startOf('month').isoWeekday() - 1;
    return Math.ceil((firstDay + day.daysInMonth()) / 7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is OK but you don't need a library, e.g.

```js
// Month is calendar month number, 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb, etc.
// Based on ISO weeks: Monday is first day of week
function getHeightOfWeekMatrix(year, month) {
  let first = (new Date(year, month-1, 1).getDay() || 7) - 1;
  let last  = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  return Math.ceil((first + last) / 7);
}

// Number of weeks for matrix 2021
let y = 2021;
let m = 'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec'.match(/\w{3}/g);
for (let i=0; i<m.length; i++)
  console.log(m[i] + ' ' + y + ': ' + getHeightOfWeekMatrix(y, i+1));
```

Most calendars seem to use 6 weeks for all months and fill it starting with the first row.

Comment: sure, we don't have to use **moment**, but in my case, it was already used(I hope in many big projects, it's used as well). Anyway, thanks for your feedback.